# How do you update multiple nodes in neo4j using cypher?

Tags: neo4j

I have products with dates I want to update in a batch operation.
here is part of the cypher I am using and it is not working:

```
match (p { Date:9102013 }) set p.Date = '9/10/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:9302013 }) set p.Date = '9/30/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:1092013 }) set p.Date = '1/0/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:1292013 }) set p.Date = '1/2/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:6182013 }) set p.Date = '6/18/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:9202013 }) set p.Date = '9/20/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:4262013 }) set p.Date = '4/26/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:4162013 }) set p.Date = '4/16/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:1142013 }) set p.Date = '1/1/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:9252013 }) set p.Date = '9/25/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:1151900 }) set p.Date = '1/1/1900' with p 
match (p { Date:4112013 }) set p.Date = '4/11/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:1242013 }) set p.Date = '1/2/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:10142013 }) set p.Date = '10/14/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:5202013 }) set p.Date = '5/20/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:212013 }) set p.Date = '2/12/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:10292013 }) set p.Date = '10/29/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:262013 }) set p.Date = '2/6/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:10242013 }) set p.Date = '10/24/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:312013 }) set p.Date = '3/12/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:5102013 }) set p.Date = '5/10/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:2282013 }) set p.Date = '2/28/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:5302013 }) set p.Date = '5/30/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:5152013 }) set p.Date = '5/15/2013' with p 
match (p { Date:362013 }) set p.Date = '3/6/2013' return p;**
```

Answer (score 3):

The example you've provided is one single Cypher statement. In this case, the first match will set the identifier `p` to match any nodes with `Date` = `9102013` (if any). The subsequent match statements will thus fail to match anything, as `p` is already bound.

You should modify this to be multiple individual queries, and use the Neo4j batch API (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) to send them all as separate cypher statements.

For example (with just the first 3), you would:

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "MATCH (p { Date: {fromDate} }) SET p.Date = {toDate} RETURN p",
    "parameters" : {
      "props" : { "fromDate" : "9102013", "toDate": "9/10/2013" }
    }
  }, {
    "statement" : "MATCH (p { Date: {fromDate} }) SET p.Date = {toDate} RETURN p",
    "parameters" : {
      "props" : { "fromDate" : "9302013", "toDate": "9/30/2013" }
    }
  }, {
    "statement" : "MATCH (p { Date: {fromDate} }) SET p.Date = {toDate} RETURN p",
    "parameters" : {
      "props" : { "fromDate" : "1092013", "toDate": "1/0/2013" }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Note that I also added parameter use, as it's faster.

Comment: thanks, chris.  i was afraid of this.  does this mean i need the node id for every node?

Comment: No, you don't. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: That url seems dead now?

Comment: Probably here: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#http-api-transactional